# Get minimum balance between two dates whether the records exist or not

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `mst_transactions` and it has fields like

`trn_id bigint(255),trn_date datetime,acc_no varchar(16),credit double(11,2),
debit double(11,2)`

I want get minimum balance between two dates from `mst_transactions` for particular account like `001256`
The balance will be calculated by following

First we need to get day wise balance for that month and then calculate this same
for every month till last date specified in `between`

I am able to get the minimum balance by for that account between that period by this query

```
SELECT *,
MIN(CASE WHEN MONTH(T1.trn_date) THEN (SELECT (SUM(credit)-SUM(debit)) FROM mst_transactions
                 WHERE trn_date <=  T1.trn_date
                 AND acc_no = T1.acc_no AND trn_id <= T1.trn_id) END) AS BALANCE
                 FROM (SELECT  trn_id,acc_no,customer_name,trn_date,(SELECT SUM(credit - debit) FROM mst_transactions 
                 WHERE trn_date <= '2017-09-30' AND acc_no= '001256') AS balanceBefore FROM  mst_transactions
                 WHERE acc_no = '001256' AND
                 trn_date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-09-30' 
                 ORDER BY trn_date) T1 
                 GROUP BY month(T1.trn_date)
                 ORDER BY T1.trn_date;
```

Now the problem is when there is only one transaction or say more between particular month it just grab that amount and then perform the operations but 
I want it to perform the operations between specified period like `'2017-04-02' to '2017-04-30'` and return all the balance between this two dates and then find minimum of it
what its doing right now is just select the records which are in the transaction table

**If there are no records between this dates it should get its balance before that date**

Please help to achieve this.

**UPDATE**
I am attaching sample data,expected o/p and current o/p please refer to solve this problem

**TRANSACTIONS**

```
 TRN_DATE    DEBIT      CREDIT       BALANCE
 31/03/2017  0.00       3500.00      3811.00
 30/04/2017  0.00       1800.00      5611.00 
 31/05/2017  0.00       2550.00      8161.00 
 01/06/2017  0.00       2425.00      10586.00 
 01/06/2017  10150.00   0.00         436.00 
 30/06/2017  0.00       2430.00      2866.00 
 31/07/2017  0.00       1940.00      4806.00 
 31/08/2017  0.00       2450.00      7256.00 
 06/09/2017  0.00       250.00       7506.00 
 06/09/2017  0.00       3930.00      11436.00 
 06/09/2017  11000.00   0.00         436.00
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
 TRN_ID ACC_NO   NAME   TRN_DATE              PREVIOUS_BAL   BALANCE
 528069 001256   JHON   2017-04-30 00:00:00   1069.00        5611.00  
 528814 001256   JHON   2017-05-31 00:00:00   1069.00        8161.00 
 528872 001256   JHON   2017-06-01 00:00:00   1069.00        436.00  
 530649 001256   JHON   2017-07-31 00:00:00   1069.00        4806.00  
 531451 001256   JHON   2017-08-31 00:00:00   1069.00        7256.00  
 531574 001256   JHON   2017-09-06 00:00:00   1069.00        436.00
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
   **CURRENT OUTPUT**

 TRN_ID ACC_NO   NAME   TRN_DATE              PREVIOUS_BAL   BALANCE
 528069 001256   JHON   2017-04-30 00:00:00   1069.00        3811.00  
 528814 001256   JHON   2017-05-31 00:00:00   1069.00        5611.00 
 528872 001256   JHON   2017-06-01 00:00:00   1069.00        436.00  
 530649 001256   JHON   2017-07-31 00:00:00   1069.00        2866.00  
 531451 001256   JHON   2017-08-31 00:00:00   1069.00        4806.00  
 531574 001256   JHON   2017-09-06 00:00:00   1069.00        436.00
```

I want to calculate every day's balance of each month between specified dates and then keep minimum balance from them
The dates specified are `'2017-04-02'` and `'2017-09-30'` so we have to calculate 6 months period balance like `'2017-04-02'` to `'2017-04-30'` then `'2017-05-02'` to `'2017-05-30'` and so on.....

As you can see the 1st transaction is on `'2017-03-31'` with balance **3811.00** and 2nd on `'2017-04-30'` with balance **5611.00** so this lies in our condition of 
`'2017-04-02' to '2017-04-30'` because balance on `'2017-04-02'` was **3811.00**
so we need to keep **3811.00** as minimum balance for that month

Comment: Incidentally, money is almost never DOUBLE. It's why DECIMAL was invented. And while bigint might represent a large number, it's never going to be anywhere near 255 digits in length.

Comment: Beyond that, for further help see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I don't have a transaction table to work with would you like to provide sample data and expected output as text in the question?

Comment: I've updated the question with sample data and required output please refer @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding you want the following, please find your words below

**"I want it to perform the operations between specified period like '2017-04-02' to '2017-04-30' and return all the balance between this two dates and then find minimum of it"**

I think we can do it in this way. Please have a look this might solve your purpose

```
SELECT MIN(RES.balance) FROM (SELECT T1.*, (SELECT SUM(credit - debit) FROM mst_transactions T2 WHERE T2.trn_date <= T1.trn_date AND T2.acc_no= '001256') balance FROM mst_transactions T1 WHERE T1.trn_date BETWEEN '2017-04-02' AND '2017-04-30' AND T1.acc_no= '001256') RES
```

Comment: I want to get minimum  balance between that period,in my database there is only one record on `'2017-04-30'` but the period is `'2017-04-02' to '2017-04-30'` so I have to look for the balance before `'2017-04-30'` till `'2017-04-02'` so that if balance on `'2017-04-30'` is **5600** and on `'2017-04-05'` its **3500** then I have to keep **3500** and discard **5600**.